Scapy IPsec AH Tunnel mode in socket
I am encountering a problem when trying to reconstruct packets in AH tunnel mode using Scapy. The packets are sent through a socket using the raw() method.
Setup:

AH Tunnel Mode Configuration:
Outer IP: src = 192.168.100.4
AH Header with Next Header set to IPv4
Inner IPv4 packet contains ICMP from 10.0.1.2 to 10.0.1.1

from scapy.all import SecurityAssociation, AH, IP, ICMP, raw

# Security Association Setup
sa = SecurityAssociation(AH, spi=0x222, auth_algo='SHA2-384-192', auth_key=b'secret key', tunnel_header=IP(src='192.168.100.4', dst='192.168.100.6'))

# Packet definition and encryption
packet = packet_from_Interface  # inner IP and ICMP details
e1 = sa.encrypt(packet)
print("AH packet:")
e1.show()

###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 140
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ah
  chksum    = 0x30e3
  src       = 192.168.100.4
  dst       = 192.168.100.6
  \options   \
###[ AH ]### 
     nh        = 4
     payloadlen= 7
     reserved  = None
     spi       = 0x222
     seq       = 2
     icv       = 266cd31bc38315f1091b8c9affb181b9ec8b33a43b9cb50d
     padding   = None
###[ IP ]### 
        version   = 4
        ihl       = 5
        tos       = 0x0
        len       = 84
        id        = 7564
        flags     = DF
        frag      = 0
        ttl       = 64
        proto     = icmp
        chksum    = 0x71b
        src       = 10.0.1.2
        dst       = 10.0.1.1
        \options   \
###[ ICMP ]### 
           type      = echo-request
           code      = 0
           chksum    = 0xc8bb
           id        = 0x7
           seq       = 0x1
           unused    = ''
###[ Raw ]### 
              load      = '\x0e\\x8fLf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12t\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567'

Actual result
Upon receiving the packet on the receiver side, it is reconstructed using Scapy as follows:
recv_packet = IP(byte_packet_received)
recv_packet.show()```

###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 128
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ah
  chksum    = 0x30ef
  src       = 192.168.100.4
  dst       = 192.168.100.6
  \options   \
###[ AH ]### 
     nh        = 4
     payloadlen= 4
     reserved  = 0
     spi       = 0x222
     seq       = 1
     icv       = ebf23a021ee0bbf47fab24ac
     padding   = 
###[ Raw ]### 
        load      = 'E\x00\x00T\\xabS@\x00@\x01yS\n\x00\x01\x02\n\x00\x01\x01\x08\x00\\xabB\x00\x08\x00\x01ߒLf\x00\x00\x00\x00X\\xe8\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567'

The reconstructed packet does not include the inner IP details, and using the AH decrypt method yields incorrect results. It appears that the problem might be related to how the packet is constructed on the receiver side.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

One of the cool features with Scapy when dissecting layers is that it tries to guess for us what the next layer is. The official way to link 2 layers is using bind_layers() function.
scapy.packet.bind_layers(scapy.AH, scapy.IP, nh=4)

